# How to excecute a command declared in child viewmodel in an MVVM app?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I've got a MainWindowVM and multiple child viewmodels inheriting from it. 
MainWindowVM inherits from ViewModelBase which implements INotifyPropertychanged.

Each view has DataContext set to CurrentViewModel defined in MainWindowVM and every button
has got a binding to a command.

If I put the commands (and other command-handling code in the constructor) in the MainWindowVM,
button clicks in every view works as expected. I set MainControlVM as CurrentViewModel in the constructor of MainWindowVM. 
Except for MainControlVM and MainWindowVM, setting commands in any other VM means they wont execute.

However, I want to have commands only in the VMs they are used.

I  found many tutorials on MVVM with only one or two viewmodels so this situation isnt an issue for them.

Edit including code:
This is the relevant code:

Part of one of the child views in XAML with a binding:

```
<Grid  DataContext="{Binding CurrentViewModel}" Margin="0,0,-186,0">
    <Button Content="Add" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="25,249,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="62" Height="32" 
Command="{Binding AddCategoryVMCommand}" />
```

MainWindowVM class contains:

```
   public ICommand AddCategoryVMCommand { get; private set; }
```

and, in the constructor:

```
AddCategoryVMCommand = new RelayCommand(() => ExecuteAddCategoryVMCommand());
```

and:

```
    protected void ExecuteAddCategoryVMCommand()
    {
        CurrentViewModel = new AddCategoryVM();
    }
```

....and the same kind of code for each command. Aso, CurrentViewModel is set in the MainWindowVM class. This is the property that the MainWindow view uses to determine which view to display along with a datatemplate:

```
        public ViewModelBase CurrentViewModel
    {
        get { return _currentViewModel; }
        set
        {
            if (_currentViewModel == value)
                           return;
            _currentViewModel = value; 
            this.RaiseNotifyPropertyChanged("CurrentViewModel");
        }
    }
```

How can I make commands execute when declared in child viewmodel?

Comment: It will be helpful to understand if you post your code,

Comment: OK, so this works, would you kindly show us what doesn't...

Comment: @StefanDenchev What doesnt work is putting the three pieces of code from my post after the line: "MainWindowVM class contains:" in  my child viewmodels instead of the MainWindowVm.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: In your child views, you are setting the DataContext of the grid to the CurrentViewModel. Are you setting a DataContext elsewhere in child, say in the constructor, and if so, how are you ensuring the ChildViewModel is set? You make no mention of other bindings in the child views and whether they work or not.

Comment: Yeah, so basically you don't want to inherit from MainWindowVM but rather ViewModelBase and use interfaces... No idea why you'd have any issues if `DataContext` is set correctly though.

Comment: @StefanDenchev The reason I want to do that is to avoid having an unnecessary amount of code in the MainWindowVM

Comment: [Take a look at this, hope it helps...](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/12/18/navigation-with-mvvm-2/)

Comment: RE Setting the DataContext in the Constructor. Binding to a UserControl does not occur until it is constructed. If the DataContext of the UserControl is set in the constructor, all external bindings will evaluate based on that DataContext. So even in the MainWindow, when you bind using what seems to be the MainWindows DataContext; at runtime, the bindings are evaluated against the UserControls DataContext. The way around it is to set the DataContext on the first content element of the UserControl. That way, external bindings still work and all internal bindings are good.

Answer (score 4):

There are a lot of comments going on, all out of sync and they appear to convolute the issue so I thought I would try to solve your problem with a basic example. The example deals solely with the command binding issue you appear to have.

I have created 3 ViewModel's, MyViewModel1 and MyViewModel2 are derived of MyViewModel. There is a command defined in the base ViewModel which is used to load the CurrentViewModel. The other 2 ViewModels contain their own commands.

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private MyViewModel currentViewModel;

    public RelayCommand<object> MyCommand { get; set; } 

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        MyCommand = new RelayCommand<object>(MyCommandExecute);
    }

    public MyViewModel CurrentViewModel
    {
        get { return currentViewModel; }
        set
        {
            if (value != currentViewModel)
            {
                currentViewModel = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    protected virtual void MyCommandExecute(object obj)
    {
        switch (int.Parse(obj.ToString()))
        {
            case 1:
                CurrentViewModel = new MyViewModel1();
                break;
            case 2:
                CurrentViewModel = new MyViewModel2();
                break;
        }
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}

public class MyViewModel1 : MyViewModel
{

    public RelayCommand<object> MyCommand1 { get; set; }

    public MyViewModel1()
    {
        MyCommand1 = new RelayCommand<object>(MyCommand1Execute);
    }

    private void MyCommand1Execute(object obj)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("MyCommand1");
    }
}

public class MyViewModel2 : MyViewModel
{

    public RelayCommand<object> MyCommand2 { get; set; }

    public MyViewModel2()
    {
        MyCommand2 = new RelayCommand<object>(MyCommand2Execute);
    }

    private void MyCommand2Execute(object obj)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("MyCommand2");
    }
}
```

The code behind the UserControl1 is

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ViewModelProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ViewModel", typeof(MyViewModel1), typeof(UserControl1));

    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public MyViewModel1 ViewModel
    {
        get { return GetValue(ViewModelProperty) as MyViewModel1; }
        set { SetValue(ViewModelProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

I have created the ViewModel Property as a DependencyProperty so I can bind to it from the MainWindow.

The Xaml of the user control is

```
<UserControl x:Class="StackOverflow._20937791.UserControl1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:this="clr-namespace:StackOverflow._20937791"
             mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <StackPanel DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type this:UserControl1}}, Path=ViewModel}">
        <Button Content="View 1 Command" Command="{Binding Path=MyCommand1}" />
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Note I have set up the DataContext on the first content element of the control. The bindings on all child elements are against the ViewModel of the UserControl while any incoming bindings (from the parent control) will be evaluated from the DataContext of that parent control.

Another point to note is that by defining the DataContext in the Xaml, you will get autocomplete in the Binding expressions which will cut down on bad expression errors.

The second UserControl is the same but the ViewModel is of type MyViewModel2.

Finally, the code for the MainWindow is

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public MyViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }
}
```

The Xaml is

```
<Window x:Class="StackOverflow._20937791.MainWindow" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:this="clr-namespace:StackOverflow._20937791"
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=ViewModel}"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="200" Width="300">
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type this:MyViewModel1}">
            <this:UserControl1 ViewModel="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type this:MyViewModel2}">
            <this:UserControl2 ViewModel="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button Content="Show View 1" Command="{Binding Path=MyCommand}" CommandParameter="1" Width="100" Margin="4" />
            <Button Content="Show View 2" Command="{Binding Path=MyCommand}" CommandParameter="2" Width="100" Margin="0 4" />
        </StackPanel>
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding Path=CurrentViewModel}" Margin="20" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

The UserControl is referenced in the main window and it has its ViewModel passed in.

The application shows a window that looks like

[image]

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the example, a great example of how to do Mvvm for beginners like me btw, but this is a very similar way of doing almost what I already did. I had a look at how I set datacontexts as your other comment suggested (except for MainWindow, putting them in only codebehind worked ) and that seems to have fixed the part of my problem relating to binding the commands.

Comment: I went back through your question and I think I see why my answer is not correct. The CurrentViewModel is not set as the ViewModel of the MainWindow, but as a property of the ViewModel of the MainWindow. I will modify my answer to match.

Comment: I have updated the answer to use a ContentControl and DataTemplates to change the display based on the CurrentViewModel.

Comment: Update shows how setting CurrentViewModel could be done correctly. However, Im trying to apply not just MVVM but solid as well, and one design principle says that every class should have a single responsibility. MainWindowVM is responsible for displaying the window and will change only because of CurrentViewModel, so nothing wrong with having some of the commands used in child views declared in the MainWindowVM. Anyway, thanks for helping out, your comment about datacontext fixed my binding problem that would have become an issue when creating other commands.

Answer (score 0):

Firt, FYI - your approach is called the strategy pattern. 
Now what you are doing sounds right but it's hard withou seeing your xaml.
Maybe you need to raise a propertychanged event after setting your vm properties?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I just edited my original post, adding code including the CurrentViewModel, which is where I raise apropertychanged event. My problem now is that this property's setter doesnt even execute at all when sending commands declared in one of my child views.

Comment: @user3155083 CurrentViewModel property is of type ViewModelBase, which dosn't expose a AddCategoryVMCommand.  You are trying to bind a datacontext's command which doesn't exists. Also, checkout your output window - it will tell you of bindings that did not bind.

Comment: Currently, commands in MainWindowVM (inheriting from ViewModelBase) and MainControlVM(inheriting from MainWindowVM) work. I dont understand how its possible they work if what you wrote was my problem.

Comment: That means thier datacontex is not binded to the CurrentViewModel (since it doesnt expose commands) but to the MainWindowVM.

Comment: This is false, type is preserved.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you would post your code .But if I havent misunderstood your question then you can try this

```
<Button Command="{Binding MainControlVM.ClickCommand}"
```

Set the binding **MainControlVM.ClickCommand** .Here ClickCommand is the name of your Command.

> **Update**

I think the issue is in Setting the CurrentViewModel. You are setting the CurrentViewModel in the Action Of Command. I think you want to set the CurrentViewModel on the basis of Command. I think this could be better by CommandParameter . Like Bind all Buttons to same Base ViewModel Command and from each Command pass the different CommandParameter and then on Command compare that CommandParameter and set CurrentViewModel accordingly.

> ViewModelBase ,Child1ViewModel ,Child2ViewModel

```
public class ViewModelBase:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ICommand _clickCommand;

    public ICommand ClickCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _clickCommand ?? (_clickCommand = new CommandHandler(MyAction,()=>true));
        }
    }

    public void MyAction(object obj)
    {
        if(obj == null )
            return;
        //if CommandParameter is Cild1VM
        if (obj.ToString() == "Child1VM")
            CurrentViewModel = new Child1ViewModel();
        //if CommandParameter is Cild1VM
        else if (obj.ToString() == "Child2VM")
            CurrentViewModel = new Child2ViewModel();
    }

    ViewModelBase _currentViewModel;

    public ViewModelBase CurrentViewModel
    {
        get { return _currentViewModel; }
        set
        {
            if (_currentViewModel == value)
                return;
            _currentViewModel = value;
            this.RaiseNotifyPropertyChanged("CurrentViewModel");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    void RaiseNotifyPropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    }
}

public class Child1ViewModel : ViewModelBase
{ }

public class Child2ViewModel : ViewModelBase
{ }
```

> xaml

```
  <StackPanel>
    <Button Content="Foo" Command="{Binding ClickCommand}" CommandParameter="Child1VM"/>
    <Button Content="Bar" Command="{Binding ClickCommand}" CommandParameter="Child2VM"/>
</StackPanel>
```

> xaml.cs

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new ViewModelBase();
    }
}
```

I hope this will give you an idea.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried this but the command name got greyed out and it didnt work when I ran it. I also tried variations of this such as declaring a vm xmlns in order to see if wrong path was the issue but no luck yet

Comment: i'm not even going to try to explain why this is so very evil (no to mention your assumption is false)...

Comment: Actually I now fixed the binding problem by changing datacontexts, but turns out I still have an issue with setting my CurrentViewModel. The commands execute now but the ExecuteCommand methods that run when command executes and are supposed to set CurrentViewModel have an issue that appears to be related to some aspect of my CurrentViewModel, whether its declaration or initialization etc I dont know yet. I looked into this example but dont have a commandhandler and dont fully understand the lambda in this context.